# How to run iphone GameCenter app from my app?

Tags: iphone, ios, game-center

I think the best way and may be only way is using the URL schemes with [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:...]. But I can't find URL scheme for game center..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can launch the Game Center app by using the `gamecenter:` URL scheme:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"gamecenter:"]];
```

Answer (score 6):

In iOS 6.0 there's a new way quite cool to show Game Center using **[GKGameCenterViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/DisplayingGameCenterUserInterfaceElements/DisplayingGameCenterUserInterfaceElements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH16-SW1)**.

For using it your view controller must acts as a delegate to the GKGameCenterViewController:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <GKGameCenterControllerDelegate>
```

And then for displaying the Game Center view:

```
- (void)showGameCenter
{
    GKGameCenterViewController *gameCenterController = [[GKGameCenterViewController alloc] init];
    if (gameCenterController != nil)
    {
        gameCenterController.gameCenterDelegate = self;
        [self presentViewController: gameCenterController animated: YES completion:nil];
    }
}

//Called when the player is done interacting with the GKGameCenterViewController
- (void)gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish:(GKGameCenterViewController *)gameCenterViewController
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

If the user it's under iOS 5.0, you can only use the URL schemes like you said before.

Answer (score -3):

Try the Apple example code. It explain how your app work with gamecenter. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GKTapper/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: it isn't what I need, I know how to work with game center, but my customer want to have the possibility to redirect user from his app directly to GameCenter app