# How can I send a user to the Game Center app?

Tags: ios, game-center, gamekit

If a user has dismissed the Game Center authentication prompt enough times, iOS will no longer show this prompt.  However, if the user wants to access a part of my game that requires the user to be authenticated (i.e. signed in) in Game Center, I would like to provide them with a button they can press that will open the Game Center app so they can do so.  Is there a way to do this?

I believe it can be done with a custom URL, but I would need to know the prefix for the Game Center app.

Comment: Seems a duplicate of :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702039/how-to-run-iphone-gamecenter-app-from-my-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until this question is closed and merged with the other question, I'll re-post the answer here:

You can launch the Game Center app by using the `gamecenter:` URL scheme:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"gamecenter:"]];
```